# Convert strings and maps into maps

Tags: rust, serde

In Rust, how do I take the inputs `"Some string"` and `{"Message":"Some string"}` and turn them both into the JSON: `{"Message": "Some string", "Source": "My app"}`? I've tried doing this via the following macro, but it doesn't work.

```
macro_rules! my_logger {
    ($level:literal, $msg:tt) => {
        let mut jsonval = json!($msg);
        if let Map(m) = $msg {
            m.insert("app", "foobar");
        } else {
            let m = Map::new();
            m.insert("app", "foobar");
            jsonval = m;
        }

        println!("{}: {}", $level, jsonval.to_string());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to log my application data using JSON. I'd use [tracing](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing), but I need the logging macros my vendor provides to connect to the logging vendor (New Relic) and I don't know how do make `tracing` do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok for you to use a function, this should work:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Message {
    #[serde(rename = "Message")]
    message: String,
}

fn concat_data(message: &str) -> serde_json::value::Value {
    let message: Message = serde_json::from_str(message)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| Message {
            message: message.to_string()
        }
    );
    json!({ "Message": message.message, "Source": "My app" })
}
```

but it is not very pretty.
The basic idea is to use [`serde_json::value::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html).

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=76a24f77ca7ae08803dea67fdab9279e).